# Modal Bootstrap sendo fechada

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap, modal

Tenho o seguinte cenário: um `link` que abre uma modal.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Sistema de Controle Operacional</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/kendo")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/blueimp/css/blueimp-gallery")

    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap/datepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="~/Content/Site.css" media="screen" />
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/excanvas_r3/excanvas.compiled.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>

<div id="divHistorico" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body…</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#divHistorico">
    <img src="~/Content/icons/history.png" style="width:24px;cursor:pointer;" title="Histórico" />
</a>


@Scripts.Render("~/lightboxGallery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/plugins/datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css" />
<script src="~/Content/plugins/datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

<script src="~/Content/datatable/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/datatable/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/datatable/date-eu.js"></script>
```

Ao clicar no `link`, a modal é aberta, porém logo em seguida é fechada, não ficando aberta como eu desejo. O que preciso fazer ?

Comment: Cara, aqui funcionou corretamente, da uma olhada na versão do seu bootstrap e certifique-se de que não tem outro script afetando isso diretamente, [exemplo funcionando](https://jsfiddle.net/yyj2ujec/)

Comment: É verdade, esse código abre um modal perfeitamente, e permanece até que você feche, não está fechando automaticamente. Veja se tem algum javascript que esteja setando algum timeout para fechar o modal.

Comment: Inseri todos meus js e css que estão sendo referenciados em ordem na minha página. @RicardoPontual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.

Comentei a seguinte linha e está funcionando normalmente:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```